# How to resolve PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant userid

Tags: php, vbulletin

I'm running vbulletin with some plugins on my server, and I'm getting a lot of these warnings in my log file, and I can't even figure out how to track down where the problems are occurring.

Here are a few:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant onlinestatusphrase - assumed 'onlinestatusphrase' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/public_html/includes/class_core.php(4684) : eval()'d code on line 6
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant adv_index - assumed 'adv_index' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/public_html/global.php(37) : eval()'d code(10) : eval()'d code on line 1
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant vsachatbox_collapsed_always - assumed 'vsachatbox_collapsed_always' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/public_html/includes/class_core.php(4684) : eval()'d code on line 36
```

I'd like to try to fix these errors to stop them from throwing warnings, but I don't even understand how to find the code that is causing the error to begin with.

If I open the files it says the error is in, I can't find those constants anywhere. Even if do a search of every file on my server, I can't find some of them.

Comment: These errors look common to the vBulletin code, and you can possibly suppress them by changing the error_reporting config for your PHP installation, but given that these are warnings now, perhaps upgrading vBulletin will help? Have a look here also: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/4316357-error_log-file-just-grow-up

Comment: the log tells you the line with error, so that's how you find it, but with out seeing code, an actual answer is hard to give. Obviously whoever wrote the plug-ins did not do a very good job

Comment: In the files `/home/public_html/includes/class_core.php` on line 4864 and `/home/public_html/global.php` on line 37 you likely have `eval($some_code);` or similar. The function `eval()` executes what is passed to it as if it were PHP code, so you'll need to trace where/how the string being passed to those functions is being generated so that you can fix the error. Honestly, I think it was a bad decision for vbulletin to include anything to do with `eval` in their core code.

Comment: Ok that helps, I didn't realize the part in the parenthesis was a line number. I was sitting here thinking how the hell there can be an error in line 1!